# Unable to integrate CQ5.6.1 with Site Catalyst

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics

I'm having difficulty in integrating AEM 5.6.1 with Site Catalyst. It allows me to connect in the configuration successfully, but does not work on the framework setup.

I've followed the [standard procedure to connect AEM to SC](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/integrating_with_adobe_marketing_cloud/sitecatalyst.html) and it accepts my login in the configuration, but fails on the framework set up with the browser message '`We were not able to login to SiteCatalyst. Please check your credentials and try again.`'. Behind the scenes in the server log;

```
12.12.2014 14:10:06.967 *WARN* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1418393406764] POST /libs/cq/analytics/sitecatalyst/service.json HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.analytics.sitecatalyst.impl.SitecatalystHttpClientImpl Data center 'https://api3.omniture.com/admin/1.3/rest/' responded with errors {"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error"}}
12.12.2014 14:10:06.967 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1418393406764] POST /libs/cq/analytics/sitecatalyst/service.json HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.analytics.sitecatalyst.impl.servlets.SitecatalystServlet Call to SiteCatalyst method 'Company.GetReportSuites' failed com.day.cq.analytics.sitecatalyst.SitecatalystException: not authenticated
```

I've tried accessing via [the API Explorer](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/get-started/api-explorer#Company.GetEndpoint) and it works.

I've tried the [troubleshooting guide](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/sitecatalystintegrationtroubleshooting.html) without success.

I can log in to Site Catalyst, I'm an admin, I am in the web services access group.

I've tried using a clean install of CQ5.6.1 with geometrixx - it doesn't work either.

I've tried this from a server and from a localhost/dev machine with the same results. No proxy. I've even tried using the shared secret as the password but then it doesn't connect at all, and fails on the configuration screen.

What might cause this to fail?

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't work with a fresh install and Geometrixx, then it's probably an Adobe bug. That's typically the first thing support will ask you about.

I would also verify using Geometrixx Outdoors, or a more recent demo site, on your fresh install, just to ensure it's not an outdated ClientLib issue.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but honestly, I would approach the integration differently. I've worked with the AEM-SC framework and it's buggy at best. It's very finicky, it doesn't REALLY work the way the documentation claims, and it requires that you're very specific about what Clientlibs are on the page.

Moving forward, I think using Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager is the better approach, for many reasons. My understanding is that it's Adobe's recommendation as well. I'd consider moving to that. In AEM 5.6.1, you'll have to customize your integration with DTM, but it's not very hard.

Comment: I agree I've worked with many clients who use AEM and they've all pretty much said the same thing: headache to get setup, headache to maintain, headache trying to find work arounds for things from limitations to bugs.  Better to pretend it doesn't exist and use the regular `s_code.js lib separately (by itself or through DTM). Not that DTM doesn't come with its own list of headaches, but they are easier headaches to deal with.

Comment: This is really useful information, given that I'm not even getting past the initial setup of the framework, I'll investigate the DTM. I'm just amazed that I can't even get past the initial first steps of setup.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Add a property on the configuration node for sitecatalyst: (eg. `/etc/cloudservices/sitecatalyst/my-sc-configuration`)

```
server=https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.2/rest/
```

it also seems to work with newer API versions such as `https://api3.omniture.com/admin/1.3/rest/`

It would appear that for 5.6.1 it ignores the OSGi configuration, at least for the configuration screens. With this extra property, the framework page loads without error and allows selection of the RSID.